# IAM permissions with Facebook credentials

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to make an IAM user that uses the AWS Javascript SDK to write to S3.

The following:

```
"Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::TestApp/facebook-${graph.facebook.com:id}/*",
]
```

Restricts the IAM user to writing to the bucket that matches the current facebook users id.  However I want to restrict them to writing to the current facebook users third_party_id.  Doing

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::TestApp/facebook-${graph.facebook.com:third_party_id}/*",
]
```

doesn't work.

Is it possible to key permissions off of other user properties as listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: You can not use the third party id to request user info from the Graph API (that’s only possible when using the FQL user table).

Comment: I see, do you know if the AWS IAM policies have some kind of syntax for reading the FQL user table?

Comment: Nope, sorry, don’t know nuffin’ about that …